# Script Shell: Delete a line from a file

Tags: shell, script

Here is my file "test.txt":

```
  172.16.68.4
  172.16.68.3
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip="172.16.68.4"
sed '/$ip/d' $1
```

Please, i'd like to delete a line from test file but it didn't work for me. 
Have an idea please  ?

Thank you so much for help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip="172.16.68.4"
sed -i "/\b\($ip\)\b/d" $1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only two things you're missing are:

- The `-i` flag in the `sed` command:

  ```
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
      edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
  ```
- You're using variables, so you should use double quotes (`"`) so the variable is expanded.

So your command should be:

```
sed -i "/$ip/d" $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to make the shell expand variables and you can take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed